# CucumberJS tests passing even though it's not possible

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, cucumberjs

I'm trying to convert some old ruby tests (which used cucumber, phantomjs and capybara) into JavaScript (using cucumber, phantomjs and selenium) as my project is 100% node based and I want to remove the Ruby dependency.

When I run the tests, they all pass. The problem is, I've not created the conditions for the test to pass yet so a pass is impossible. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Here is my world.js file:

```
var {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');
var seleniumWebdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = seleniumWebdriver.By,
    until = seleniumWebdriver.until;

function CustomWorld() {
  this.driver = new seleniumWebdriver.Builder()
  .withCapabilities(seleniumWebdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs())
  .build()

  // Returns a promise that resolves to the element
  this.waitForElement = function(locator) {
    var condition = seleniumWebdriver.until.elementLocated(locator);
    return this.driver.wait(condition)
  }
}

defineSupportCode(function({setWorldConstructor}) {
  setWorldConstructor(CustomWorld)
});
```

And here is my step definitions file:

```
require('dotenv').config();
var chalk = require('chalk');
var {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');
var seleniumWebdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = seleniumWebdriver.By,
    until = seleniumWebdriver.until;

defineSupportCode(function({ Given, When, Then }) {

  Given(/^I show my environment$/, function (next) {
    console.log(chalk.green("Running against:" + process.env.TARGET_URI))
    next()
  })

  When(/^I visit "(.*?)"$/, function (url) {
    return this.driver.get(url);
  })

  Then(/^I should be on "([^"]*)"$/, function(page_name) {
    this.driver.get(process.env.TARGET_URI+'/'+page_name)
    .then(function() {
      return this.driver.getCurrentUrl();
    })
  })

  Then(/^I should see "([^"]*)"$/, function (text) {
    var xpath = "//*[contains(text(),'" + text + "')]";
    var condition = seleniumWebdriver.until.elementLocated({xpath: xpath});
    return this.driver.wait(condition, 5000);
  });
})
```

The only possible tests that could be passing there are: `When(/^I visit "(.*?)"$/...` and `Given(/^I show my environment$/...`

For reference, here is my .feature file too:

```
Feature: Test the global header works as expected

Scenario: Header components should exist
    Given I visit "/hello"
    Then I expect to see a ".c-logo-bar" element
    And I expect to see a ".c-search-bar" element
    And I expect to see a ".c-main-nav-bar" element
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I think it is the other way around. Until unless you add failure using assert the test should not fail

Comment: No failed conditions is a pass.